# Unemployment claim

Tags: united-states, income, unemployment

I worked in Virginia until 12/30/19 and was transferred by my company to Louisville, Ky. Now with the Coronavirus, I am being layed off or have my hours reduced to 15 hours. I want to file for unemployment but what state would that be. I tried Kentucky and it denied me because the base period coverage is 1/1/2019 to 12/31/19 and I just started in the state on 12/31/19(Same company). Would I need to file for Virginia?